# Remote Desktop Services stopped working after domain change

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, remote-desktop-services

I had Remote Desktop Services (RD Session Host deployment) functioning properly on the Windows Server 2012 R2.
The server had to be moved to another domain. That went well but now Remote Desktop Services completely lost the configuration which I expected.

I tried removing the roles and features and adding them again but during the role installation I get error on RD Web role installation.

Is it possible to completely remove previous Remote Desktop Deployment and start from scratch? It seems that uninstallation of the roles doesn't remove everything.

Also I suspect that something else causes the problem as I get errors in Event Viewer from ESENT:

```
svchost (3048) Database recovery/restore failed with unexpected error -1032.

svchost (3048) An attempt to open the file "C:\Windows\system32\LogFiles\Sum\Api.log" for read / write access failed with system error 5 (0x00000005): "Access is denied. ".  The open file operation will fail with error -1032 (0xfffffbf8).

svchost (3048) An attempt to open the file "C:\Windows\system32\LogFiles\Sum\SystemIdentity.mdb" for read / write access failed with system error 5 (0x00000005): "Access is denied. ".  The open file operation will fail with error -1032 (0xfffffbf8).
```

Comment: You didn't explain exactly what stopped working.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't add more details.
It completely stopped working. I couldn't configure it any more. The RDS page in the Server Manager says that there is no deployment even if I add it via add features menu.
Anyway I've decided to do a complete reinstall as it seems it is a a big hassle to find a reason and fix it instead of just doing a reinstall.

Comment: As you may have discovered by now, you have to preface your comment with an `@username` if you want your intended recipient to be notified. The only time this isn't required is when your recipient is the author of either the Q or an A in the Q&A (such as this comment from me to you). In this case, Joe never saw your follow-up comment. He's pretty good about replying, so I'm confident that's why you never heard back from him.